# Class with std::array of objects without default constructors

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, uniform-initialization

So let's assume I have the following class

```
class NoDefaultConstructor {
    NoDefaultConstructor() = delete;
    ...
};
```

And I have another class which has an array of type `NoDefaultConstructor` and other members

```
class Wrapper {
    std::array<NoDefaultConstructor, 2> arr;
    ... 
};
```

How can I initialize the array in the constructor for `Wrapper` (maybe in the initializer list using an `std::intializer_list`)?

More specifically, is the only way I can pass on arguments to the array constructor in the initializer list for `Wrapper` to have a construct similar to the following?  I was thinking of doing this because the size of the array might change in the future.

```
template <typename... Values>
Wrapper(Values&&... values) : arr{std::forward<Values>(values)...} {}
```

Comment: You could store `std::unique_ptr<NoDefaultConstructor>` instances in the array instead of just `NoDefaultConstructor`.

Comment: I explored that idea but I didn't want to use it because I could rather have used an `std::vector` instead in that case

Comment: Search for questions on how to initialize data members w/o default constructors. There are plenty of those on SO.

Comment: @juanchopanza this is slightly different from the general case

Comment: Not significantly different. Same thing, really.

Comment: I see you edited your question, but you seem to still be ignoring the fact that `std::array` has no nontrivial constructors. If you're going to do aggregate initialization, like I said, you can make `Wrapper` into an aggregate. See the coliru link I posted in a comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::array` is required to be an aggregate. Therefore it has no nontrivial constructors, but can be initialized using aggregate initialization. Note that aggregate initialization involves a *braced-init-list* (that is, a brace-enclosed list of initializers) but not an `std::initializer_list` object.

```
class Wrapper {
  public:
    Wrapper() : arr {MakeNoDefaultConstructor(123),
                     MakeNoDefaultConstructor(456)} {}
    //              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ braced-init-list
  private:
    std::array<NoDefaultConstructor, 2> arr;
};
```

---

**EDIT** A constructor with variadic arguments could be possible here like so

```
#include <array>
struct NoDefault {
    NoDefault() = delete;
    NoDefault(int) {}
};
struct Wrapper {
    template <typename... Args>
    Wrapper(int b_in, Args&&... args) : b{b_in}, a{args...} {}
    int b;
    std::array<NoDefault, 3> a;
};
int main() {
    std::array<NoDefault, 2> a {12, 34};
    Wrapper w {23, 12, 34, 19};
}
```

This of course can be further tightly constrained by adding `enable_if`s

Comment: Is there no way to forward some arguments to this constructor?  Is the only way to use variadic templates?

Comment: @Curious I don't understand, could you perhaps elaborate?

Comment: I wanted the class constructor to accept parameters that would then get forwarded to the array constructor

Comment: I don't see the variadic templates.

Comment: @Curious To what array constructor? Like I said, `std::array` has no nontrivial constructors. Are you saying you want `Wrapper` to exhibit the same construction semantics as the `std::array` type it wraps? If that's the case, you should make `Wrapper` into an aggregate as well. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6affc3571b9c956

Comment: Edited my question!

Answer (score 3):

> How can I initialize the array in the constructor for Wrapper (maybe in the initializer list using an std::intializer_list)?

Just as you would for any other member, but use uniform initialization because `std::array` doesn't have any constructors.

> More specifically, is the only way I can pass on arguments to the array constructor in the initializer list for Wrapper to have a construct similar to the following?

No, why would you need to use a variadic templates for a fixed number of arguments?

Just ... write the constructor, with arguments:

```
class Wrapper {
    std::array<NoDefaultConstructor, 2> arr;

    Wrapper(const NoDefaultConstructor& a, const NoDefaultConstructor& b)
    : arr{ a, b }
    { }
};
```

Comment: Edited my question regarding why I was thinking of using variadic arguments, does it make more sense now?